# vb.net grouping data and name column from data value

Tags: datagridview, grouping

Current database:

```
NAME          WEEK         COLOR

AAA            1           Green

AAA            2           Blue

AAA            3           Blue

BBB            1           Red

BBB            3           Green
```

Output:

```
NAME     WEEK1      WEEK2       WEEK3

AAA      Green      Blue        Blue

BBB      Red                    Green

Dim weekOfyear = calendar.GetWeekOfYear( dateNow, _ dfi.CalendarWeekRule, _ DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
w1 = weekOfyear - 2 
w2 = weekOfyear - 1 
w3 = weekOfyear 
w4 = weekOfyear + 1 
w5 = weekOfyear + 2 
Dim c As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With c .CommandText = "select [Engineer],[Week],[Status] from [Approved Jobs] where [Week] = '" & w1 & "' and '" & w2 &     "' group by [Engineer]" .Connection = con 
End With
Dim ad As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(c)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ad.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Good day guys. I really need your help guys. I've this project in school, as seen above, my current database and my expected output to datagridview. I would just like to ask to what method can this be achieved. I've been trying to group by name in sql but I cant make the expected output. Would really love to hear for your ideas.

TIA

Comment: What have you tried? You may want to peruse… [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) …  AND [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: honestly I don't have any idea. but I've tried grouping it by name via sql. but no good

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish what you have posted. There are also other factors that may determine which path to take. In your comment, you stated _I've tried grouping it by name via sql. but no good_…  unfortunately “no good” is not really a good description of the problem. Post what you have tried, explain what you are expecting and show what error(s) or incorrect output that is not expected. Again my last comment links to how to ask a question that will increase your chances of getting an answer. If you have tried with sql and it doesn’t work… post that portion of code.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this and here. first of is I get the week number of this day, then week number of last 2 weeks ago until 2 weeks after now. then get the data from database where weeks are present. Arrange data as seen on output.

Comment: When I said "post your code"... I meant you should edit your question to post the code in a formatted fashion. After you do this you can delete the code comment.

Comment: How is your original data stored? In a `DataTable`? How do you plan to display the results? Do you have to use OldDb? Your code is incomplete and is hard to understand as far a grouping by name goes.

Comment: original data is from access database. Output should be on a datagridview.